# Django REST Framework, ordering m2m serialization via a through table

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to produce JSON using Django REST Framework (3.3.1), which should order a m2m field using a through model. This works in normal django views - the ordering is honoured (ie in the admin lists). However, using a standard DRF set of ModelSerializers, the through table specified on the django models is not used for the ordering of the returned m2m set.

Is there an easy way to achieve the ordering that i'm after? Or do i need to generate the data and return in my own DRF responses?

I have the following models:

```
class Pitch(models.Model):
    """ A pitch like 'A4" (A at octave 4) with midi note - ie 60 = middle C (C3) """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    midi_note = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['midi_note']
        verbose_name_plural = 'pitches'


class Pattern(models.Model):
    """ ie A Major """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    pitches = models.ManyToManyField(Pitch, through='PitchPosition')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{0}".format(self.name)


class PitchPosition(models.Model):
    """
    The through table for a pitch in a pattern, needed as 
    scales/arpeggios go up and down, so pitches appear 
    twice in the list

    """
    pattern = models.ForeignKey(Pattern)
    pitch = models.ForeignKey(Pitch)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{0} ({1})".format(self.pitch, self.pattern)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['pattern', 'order']
```

Serializing the data with DRF, the through table ordering is not being honoured:

```
class PitchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pitch
        fields = ('name', 'midi_note')


class PatternSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    pitches = PitchSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Pattern
        fields = ('name', 'pitches')
```

Produces:

```
[
    {
        "name": "D Major",
        "pitches": [
            {
                "name": "D4",
                "midi_note": 62
            },
            {
                "name": "D4",
                "midi_note": 62
            },
            {
                "name": "E4",
                "midi_note": 64
            },
            {
                "name": "E4",
                "midi_note": 64
            },
            {
                "name": "F#4",
                "midi_note": 66
            },
            {
                "name": "F#4",
                "midi_note": 66
            },
            {
                "name": "G4",
                "midi_note": 67
            },
            {
                "name": "G4",
                "midi_note": 67
            },
            {
                "name": "A4",
                "midi_note": 69
            },
            {
                "name": "A4",
                "midi_note": 69
            },
            {
                "name": "B4",
                "midi_note": 71
            },
            {
                "name": "B4",
                "midi_note": 71
            },
            {
                "name": "C#5",
                "midi_note": 73
            },
            {
                "name": "C#5",
                "midi_note": 73
            },
            {
                "name": "D5",
                "midi_note": 74
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: It's not clear what ordering you expect, do you want the pitches ordered by name? Also, in JSON (like many dictionary data structures), the order of the keys is, by definition, not meaningful. The consuming client can and should rearrange the received data as needed for any required presentation state.

Comment: Fair enough about the order of the JSON keys not being meaningful. The order I want (or the data i want in the JSON) is the 'order' field from the PitchPosition model, this has:   class Meta:  ordering = ['pattern', 'order']. For my purposes it would be enough to have all the pitches in a pattern, in the order defined by the pitchposition.order field. NB the pitch can appear more than once in a pattern - ie A, B, C, B, A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) objects to control the order of `PitchPosition` objects when you pass the `Pattern` queryset to the serializer.

Comment: Thanks Dhiraj, I'll give that a go.